# Find the Wronskian of the second-order homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, wronskian

Problem:

> Show that if $p$ is differentiable and $p(t)>0$, then the Wronskian $W(t)$ of two solutions of two solutions of $[p(t)y']' +q(t) y=0$ is $W(t)=c/p(t)$, where $c$ is a constant.

Consider the second-order homogeneous equation
\begin{equation}
 y''+ p(t) y'+q(t)=0.
\end{equation}

As I know, the existence of two solutions is ensured whenever $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ are continuous over some open interval. However, in the problem, we don't know the continuity of $p'(t)$ and $q(t)$. I'm confused whether the Wronskian can be calculated without the existence of solutions. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have two solutions, then for $W(t)=W[y_1,y_2](t)$, as we know the desired result, consider
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}(p(t)W(t))&=\frac{d}{dt}\det\pmatrix{y_1(t)&y_2(t)\\py_1'(t)&py_2'(t)}
\\
&=\det\pmatrix{y_1'(t)&y_2'(t)\\p(t)y_1'(t)&p(t)y_2'(t)}+\det\pmatrix{y_1(t)&y_2(t)\\(p(t)y_1'(t))'&(p(t)y_2'(t))'}
\\
&=0+\det\pmatrix{y_1(t)&y_2(t)\\-q(t)y_1(t)&-q(t)y_2(t)}
\\
&=0
\end{align}
Thus $p(t)W(t)=c$ is constant.

---

For the existence of solutions use $v=py'$ as the second state component in the first-order system
\begin{align}
y'(t)&=\frac1{p(t)}v(t)\\
v'(t)&=-q(t)y(t)
\end{align}
So for the existence of solutions it is sufficient that the positive function $p$ is continuous.

Comment: Right, but I wonder whether we can assume the existence of the solutions $y_1,y_2$ without the continuity condition...

Comment: You do not even need that $p$ is differentiable. All coefficients in a linear system need to be continuous to apply the basic existence-and-uniqueness theorems. If you want to switch to the non-continuous context, you need to clearly define what coefficient functions you consider admissible, else you land in the chaotic wilderness.

Comment: For differentiability of $v=py'$, it seems to need the assumption '$p$ is differentiable'. I agree to your opinion. I thought the problem need to be more clarified about coefficient functions' condition.

Comment: No, it does not need it, differentiability of $v$ is a consequence of the existence theorem. In a linear system $u'=Au$ the matrix $A$ needs only be continuous to get a differentiable solution. There is no guarantee that $y$ will be twice differentiable, the "defects" of $p$ and $y'$ compensate.

Comment: I don't know how to write $v'(t)=-q(t)y(t)$ without assuming differentiability of $v$ in a linear system. In my opinion, it seems like that this expression already used the condition...

Comment: No. The domain of a differential equation (not the domain of the right-side function) are continuously differentiable functions. It is not a given thing that any such function actually satisfies the equation. That is only established by the conditions in the existence theorems. But you can still write down the equation for the hypothetical solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Since $p$ is differentiable and is different from zero, rewrite the differential equation as :
$$y''+\dfrac {p'}py'+\dfrac {q}{p}y=0$$
Use [Abel's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_identity) :
$$W=c\exp \int -\dfrac {p'}{p}dt$$
You can also easily prove that:
$$W'=-\dfrac {p'}pW$$
where $W$ is the wronskian.

Comment: However, we don't know the continuity of p'/p and q/p... how to apply the identity??